# Access variable in jsp tag files inside a loop?

Tags: jsp, file, tags

I try to create a jsp tag file, which will call a helper class to print the input object. So I created a file  /WEB-INF/tags/formatter.tag

```
<%@ tag import="package.Formatter"%>
<%@ attribute name="value" required="true" type="java.lang.Object" %>              
<%=Formatter.format(pageContext.getAttribute("value"))%>
```

So that I can call it in JSP like:

```
<t:formatter value="${obj}" />
```

But I found that it will not work inside a loop, e.g.

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="i">
   <t:formatter value="${i.property}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

I suspect that I should not get the attribute from `pageContext`. But I'm not sure. Any one know about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get an error or the wrong result?

Comment: websphere got some ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException, thrown by at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.validator.ValidateVisitor.getELExpressions

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

First, convert your formatter to be a standard Java bean (i.e. make the format method non static, have no arg constructor, etc.). The, change the tag to be:

```
<%@ tag import="package.Formatter" %>
<%@ attribute name="value" required="true" type="java.lang.Object" %> 
<jsp:useBean id="formatter" class="package.Formatter" />             
${formatter.format(value)}
```

Comment: In my case, I need to pass two parameter. e.g.  ${formatter.format(value,2)}. This results in JSP error: unable to parse EL function

Answer (score 0):

Add following. Most likely your problem is that nothing in "c" tag is getting processed.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```